# Open maps with specific address iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, dictionary, street-address, apple-maps

I am trying to make my application open the apple maps application and have the address be pulled up. I tried this :

```
- (IBAction)openInMaps:(id)sender {
    NSString *addressString = @"http://maps.apple.com/?q=1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:addressString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

and this :

```
- (IBAction)openInMaps:(id)sender {
    NSString *addressString = @"http://maps.apple.com/?q=1_Infinite_Loop,_Cupertino,_CA";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:addressString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

But the button just acts like its hooked to nothing. But this does work :

```
- (IBAction)openInMaps:(id)sender {
    NSString *addressString = @"http://maps.apple.com/?q=Cupertino,CA";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:addressString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

So, whenever their is a space it doesn't work. How can I open this address?

Comment: give the documentation a whirl https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Comment: Thanks man, didn't even know that was there... I'll check it out

Comment: I go it : NSString *addressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?q=1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+CA"];

Comment: Don't needlessly use `stringWithFormat:`. Just assign the string directly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to properly escape the spaces in the URL:

```
NSString *addressString = @"http://maps.apple.com/?q=1%20Infinite%20Loop,%20Cupertino,%20CA";
```

Edit - it seems using `+` instead of `%20` for the spaces solves the problem.

So to get it to work properly you must use this :

```
NSString *addressString = @"http://maps.apple.com/?q=1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+CA";
```

Comment: Still acts like the button does nothing. However, I am getting the error : Invalid conversion specifier 'I'. I know what it means, but how do u fix?

Answer (score 11):

Swift 2 version that is formatted nicely, safely handles optionals, and won't crash your app:

```
let baseUrl: String = "http://maps.apple.com/?q="
let encodedName = "address".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()) ?? ""
let finalUrl = baseUrl + encodedName
if let url = NSURL(string: finalUrl) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I do it in Objective C...I always try the Waze Map first, because to be honest, it's awesome sauce, I added the PLIST file permissions at the end:

```
- (IBAction)getDirectionsAction:(id)sender {
    NSURL *googleURL = [[NSURL alloc]
        initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?daddr=%@", @"44.294349,-70.326973"]];

    NSURL *googleWebURL =
        [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%@",
                                                                 @"44.294349,-70.326973"]];

    NSURL *appleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=311+East+Buckfield+Road+Buckfield+Maine"];

    NSURL *wazeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"waze://?ll=44.294349,-70.326973&navigate=yes"];

    // Lets try the Waze app first, cuz we like that one the most
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:wazeURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:wazeURL
                                           options:@{}
                                 completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
                                 }];
        return;
    }

    // Lets try the Apple Maps app second (great success rate)
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:appleURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appleURL
                                           options:@{}
                                 completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
                                 }];
        return;
    }
    // If those 2 are unsuccessful, let's try the Google Maps app
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:googleURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:googleURL
                                           options:@{}
                                 completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
                                 }];
        return;
    }
    // Uh, oh...Well, then lets launch it from the web then.
    else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:googleWebURL
                                           options:@{}
                                 completionHandler:^(BOOL success){

                                 }];
    }
}
```

**FOR PLIST FILE**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>http://maps.apple.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>http://maps.google.com/</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>waze</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>For Use for directions</string>
```

[image: 1x]

[image: 2x]

[image: 3x]

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3 version:

```
let baseUrl: String = "http://maps.apple.com/?q="
let encodedName = "yourAddress".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
let finalUrl = baseUrl + encodedName
if let url = URL(string: finalUrl)
    {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Swift 2

 let baseUrl : String = "http://maps.google.com/?q="
            let name : String = tableCellData[indexPath.row]
            let encodedName = "address of yours"
            name.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
            let finalUrl = baseUrl + encodedName!

            let url = NSURL(string: finalUrl)!
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```